# Matrix where $a_{ij}=|i−j|$ for $n=100$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I need to calculate the determinant of $A$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ where $a_{ij}=|i−j|$ for $n=100$.

What does $a_{ij}=|i−j|$ mean exactly?
I think $n$ is the size. So there are $100$ elements?

Comment: It denotes the element corresponding to $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column. For e.g., $a_{21} = |2-1| = 1$

Comment: It has $100\times 100$ elements so $10^4$ elements

Comment: The matrix is of size $100\times 100$. The $(i,j)$- entry is the absolute value of $i-j$.

Comment: As for finding the determinant, I would suggest finding it for $A_2$, $A_3$, maybe $A_4$, try to find a pattern and prove it by induction.

Comment: @epiliam oh I see thank you. I'm doing my assignment and I need to compute determinant with LU factorization. do you know how to use matlab by the way?

Comment: @dodd thank you do you know how to use matlab by the way?

Comment: Ok, so numerical. Gonna say, as I saw no obvious way to do it by hand. Ignore my previous comment and add that to the question

Comment: @epiliam yes so I have code for calculating determinant now but the part im worried about is " when two rows of A are interchanged, the sign of the determinant changes. "

Comment: I use Maple more than mathlab. But I believe that Wolfram alpha is good enough for this.

Comment: do you know how to create a 100x100 matrix? so I can test with my code on matlab/.?

Comment: You need to add that to the question. It was not clear that you were asking how to solve it using code, and not how to solve it by hand - I thought it was the latter. Btw I think that $\det A_n = (-1)^{n-1}2^{n-2}(n-1)$. So I think you should get $\det A_{100} = -2^{98}\cdot 99$

Comment: @epiliam I'm sorry what do you mean by $det A_{100} = -2^{98]\cdot 99$?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you not understand the statement, or have an issue that I had a wrong bracket? I had edited my comment to fix it before you even made your comment

Comment: I don't understand detA100=−2^98⋅99 . What is this line?

Comment: I am saying the determinant is $-2^{98}\cdot 99$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115115/discussion-between-lolads-and-epiliam).

Answer (score 1):

We can replace rows $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{100}$ of this matrix by $A_1, A_2-A_1, A_3-A_2, \dots, A_{100}-A_{99}$ without changing the determinant. This turns the matrix into
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & 98 & 99 \\
      1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 \\
      1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & -1 
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
Expanding by minors along the first row, we see that most of the terms cancel. The first cancels because we're multiplying by $0$. The next $98$ of them cancel because the minor has both an all $1$ column and an all $-1$ column, which are linearly dependent. So we're just left with $-99$ times the determinant of
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1  \\
      1 & 1 & -1  & \cdots & -1  \\
      1 & 1 & 1  & \cdots & -1  \\
     \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
      1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
Applying the same trick with differences of rows as we started with, we turn this matrix into
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1  \\
      0 & 2 & 0  & \cdots & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 2  & \cdots & 0  \\
     \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
      0 & 0 & 0  & \cdots & 2
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has determinant $2^{98}$, because it's upper triangular. So our final answer is $-99 \cdot 2^{98}$.